# How to open links based on which parent is clicked Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing my FAQs page for that i have used questions as links and answers in paragraph tags. I want to show answer of its respective question when its question link is clicked, i have coded till now and its working perfect.

**My problem** is that i have some answers where i have used links as well. so when i click such question link it shows its answer (Fine) but when i click the link in answer it hides the whole answer which i don't want. i want to open that link in new tab, and when i click question again it should hide that answer.

HTML

```html
<div class="pageContents">
  <div class="list_Q" id="Q3">
    <a class="que" href="#">
      <h5><strong>Q) </strong>
        How can I test EPX before I buy it? 
      </h5>
    </a>
    <p id="ans-pop"><strong>A) </strong>Demo link for EPX is <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com/" class="link_read">Here </a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="list_Q" id="Q15">
    <a class="que" href="#">
      <h5>
        <strong>Q) </strong>How can I create Endicia account I'd? 
      </h5>
    </a>
    <p id="ans-pop"><strong>A) </strong>Visit <a target="_blank" href="http://www.endicia.com/" class="link_read">Endicia</a>&nbsp;for 
      creating Endicia account.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#ans-pop {
  display: none;
}

.list_Q {
  BORDER-BOTTOM: #333333 1px dotted;
  MARGIN-BOTTOM: 5px;
}

.list_Q H5 {
  PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px;
  PADDING-LEFT: 5px;
  PADDING-RIGHT: 5px;
  MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px;
  BACKGROUND: #ededed;
  COLOR: #d80d0d;
  FONT-SIZE: 12px;
  FONT-WEIGHT: normal;
  PADDING-TOP: 5px;
}

.list_Q P {
  PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px;
  PADDING-LEFT: 5px;
  PADDING-RIGHT: 5px;
  COLOR: #333333;
  FONT-SIZE: 12px;
  PADDING-TOP: 5px;
}
```

Jquery

```js
$('.list_Q').click(function () {
  var status = $(this).attr('id');
  var fix = '#' + status + ' #ans-pop';

  if ($(fix).is(":not(:visible)")) {
    $(fix).show(500); 
  } else {
    $(fix).hide(500);  
  }
  return false;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P45bE/127/)

Comment: since you have attached the click event to entire div the click is triggered even if you click anywhere in the div

Comment: and ids must be unique you have id `ans-pop` to all your paras

Comment: kindly check http://jsfiddle.net/P45bE/131/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the `target` is not `a` tag like this:

```
if ($(event.target).is('a')) {
   return;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P45bE/129/

**Update**

In the below fiddle the code close the opened question while it show the clicked.

Hide the opened answer using `$('.ans-pop:visible').hide(500);`

**Important** I replaced the `id="ans-pop"` to `class="ans-pop"` because `id` attribute must be unique. Especially in this case.

http://jsfiddle.net/P45bE/132/

Comment: Thanks simplest :)

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck.

Comment: how can i add one more thing that if any closed question is clicked any open question should close and open that respective question clicked. pls update fiddle on it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class on your link and stop the event propagation on the click of your link.

```
<a target="_blank" class="test" href="http://www.endicia.com/" class="link_read">Endicia</a>


$('.test').click(function (e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P45bE/128/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this, try to replace your code with this

```
$('.list_Q a').click(function (){
var status = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.stopPropagation();` in the anchors you want to click:

```
$("a[href!=#]").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P45bE/130/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
    <a href="#answer_1" class="question"><h5><strong>Q) </strong> Question number 1 </h5></a>
    <div id="answer_1" class="answer">
        <p><strong>A)</strong> Answer, with an <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com/" class="link_read">external link</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq">
    <a href="#answer_2" class="question"><h5><strong>Q) </strong>Here's another question</h5></a>
    <div id="answer_2" class="answer">
        <p><strong>A)</strong> Another answer, with another <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com/" class="link_read">external link</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.question').on('click', function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(href).toggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display:none;
}
```

- Seeing as you're using links, I've added the ID of the answer as the href so the questions and answers are linked, even without the JS.
- In jQuery, the href is then grabbed from the link and used to select and show/hide the answer div
- External links work as they normally would, as the jQuery code doesn't affect them in any way